# Javascript Object into array move object property name into array key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this nested objects:

```
"State Names": {
    "State Cities": {
        "Los Angeles": {
            "about": "story",
            "zip": "91721"
        },
    }
}
```

and I was trying to make it look like this:

```
state: {
    city: [
        "name": "Los Angeles",
        "about": "story",
        "zip": "91721"
    ]
}
```

I've tried below code:

```
    var o = {
        "State Names": {
            "State Cities": {
                "Los Angeles": {
                    "about": "story",
                    "zip": "91721"
                },
            }
        }
    }
    var v = o["State Names"];
    var z = v["State Cities"];
    const result = Object.keys(z).map(i => z[i]);

    const state = {
        city: [...result]
    }
    this.setState({
        state
    })
```

But my result doesn't showing city names, only showing about and zip. How do I include object key name into array as property during the map function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) (or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)) to clone the city object, and add a name property:

```js
const o = {"State Names":{"State Cities":{"Los Angeles":{"about":"story","zip":"91721"}}}};
const cities = o['State Names']['State Cities'];
const result = Object.keys(cities).map(name => ({ ...cities[name], name }));

const state = {
  city: [...result]
};

console.log(state);
```